# Meteor with FBGraph NPM package - pagination and increasing limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, npm, meteorite

I followed a tutorial on (www).andrehonsberg.com/article/facebook-graph-api-meteor-js
Which is a guide for using FBgraph NPM package (www).npmjs.org/package/fbgraph with Meteor.

It all works out fine, I tweaked it to suit my need which is basically having it count the number of tags in a comment on a Facebook object ID, and if the same commenter has made several comments, it would count towards a total stored in an object.

**Problem**
is it stops counting after 25 entries. It's to say that the Graph API default limit of 25 is what gets passed. So I'm trying to figure out how to up the limit on it.

**What didn't work**

adding `?limit=100` to the query URL.
modifying `line 17 in facebook.js` by adding `{limit: 100}` like so:

```
var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
    self.fb[method](query, {limit: 100}, function(err, res) {
        done(null, res);
    });
```

adding `{limit:100}` to line 5 `this.options` like so:

```
this.options = {
    timeout: 3000,
    limit: 100,
    pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
    headers: {connection: 'keep-alive'}
}
```

**CODE**

https://github.com/khalidaljaaidi/CountTags
File in question: (www).github.com/khalidaljaaidi/CountTags/blob/master/server/facebook.js

Answer (score 0):

I looked around a bit in the NPM FB Graph and it looks like the problem might be coming from var boundary in form_data.js. If you go to packages/npm/package/node_modules/fbgraph/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib there should be a file called form_data.js. On line 162 there is this code:

```
FormData.prototype._generateBoundary = function() {
  // This generates a 50 character boundary similar to those used by Firefox.
  // They are optimized for boyer-moore parsing.
  var boundary = '--------------------------';
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    boundary += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString(16);
  }

  this._boundary = boundary;
};
```

I haven't tested it out, however you could try increasing 24 to see if you're able to up the post limit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't help. This function creates a boundary that is used in form data. This boundary consists of 26 hyphens, followed by 24 random values